# Using tensorflow models both as standalone and subgraphs

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, python-3.7

I want to do the following:

Create a model that can be used in two ways;

1. Use it as a standalone model (fit it using some data)
2. Use it as a subgraph in another model

Ideally I want to have a class `MyModel` that I can initialize `model=MyModel(hyperparameters)` and which supports `model.fit(X, Y)`, `model.predict(X)` and `model.evaluate(X, Y)`  methods.

At the same time I want to be able to feed it `tf.Variables` in order to use it as part in  a bigger graph `latent_variable = model(x)` where `x` is a `tf.Variable`

Is there any way this is possible to do in `tensorflow`? Using tf.keras.Model doesn't work because it always returns a `tf.Tensor`, but not `tf.Variable` even if a `tf.Variable` is fed in.

Comment: Did you try using it with keras, by applying `tf.conver_to_tensor(x)` before passing it into your model?

Comment: @bluesummers does this still allow me to backprop w.r.t. the input Variable?

Comment: I believe it does, I would verify anyhow. From my experiments a `tf.keras.Model` instance can be used as a layer in another `tf.keras.Model` instance